# How to export csv file after search data in Django 2?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-2.0

I have a search function that returns json via ajax, but I also want to export the data to a csv file.

It occurred to me to do another function to export the data, which brings the search function

I'm doing it like this:

```
  def search(request):
    date = request.GET.get('date')

    queryset = List.objects.filter(date=date)
    data = serializers.serialize('json', queryset)

    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')

  def export_to_csv(request):
    data = search(request)
    # But that does not bring the search data
    print(data)
    # <HttpResponse status_code=200, "application/json">
```

I hope you understand my question, some ideas or suggestions?

Comment: data is response object, so many properties inside it, try data.text to get response output. You can check properties inside data by dir(data). Then you can use pandas to export data as csv check pandas documentation http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with simply extracting the logic which retrieves and serializes the data into a helper function, which can be a part of your `views.py` (or, probably a better approach, moved to a helper/utility module) e.g.:

```
def get_search_data(date=None):
    queryset = List.objects.all()        
    if date:
        queryset = queryset.filter(date=date)

    return serializers.serialize('json', queryset)

def search(request):
    data = get_search_data(request.GET.get('date'))
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')

def export_to_csv(request):
    data = get_search_data()
    ...
    print(data)
    # <HttpResponse status_code=200, "application/json">
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but in the `export_to_csv` function the data is an empty list [], only in `search` if it brings data.

Comment: Are you sure that the `date` is present in the `request.GET` dict? Are you sure there are any entries for that filter?

Comment: The `date` is empty for the export function

Comment: Well, I guess that's your problem then - try with the updated answer now where the `date` is optional.